# Error : local variable 'key' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I want to update entity with using key but something is wrong. My codes here :

```
def post(self):
        username = self.request.get("contentb")
        header, response = client.request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name='+username+'&count=5000')
        ids = [str(id) for id in json.loads(response)["ids"]]
        messages = []
        userlist = [user.username for user in User.query().fetch(projection=["username"])]
        if username not in userlist:
            user = User()
            user.username = username
            user.follower_list = ids
            key = user.put()
            messages.append("Ok we added you")
        else:
            followerlist = [user.follower_list[0] for user in User.query().filter(User.username == username).fetch(projection=["follower_list"])]
            if len(set(followerlist)-set(ids)) == 0:
                messages.append("No one has unfollowed you :)")
            else:
                for i in set(followerlist)-set(ids):
                    messages.append(str(i) + " " + "unfollowed you")  

            user = key.get()
            user.follower_list = ids
            user.put()
            messages.append("We updated your followerlist")
```

But I get error :

```
user = key.get()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'key' referenced before assignment
```

Please can you tell where am I wrong ?

Comment: `user = user_key.get()` isn't even in your code. Is there more to your code?

Comment: but firstly I created a user so I used "key = user.put()". After that I want to update user ??

Comment: @AmyObrian: Look at the error message. The `UnboundLocalError` points to a name `user_key`. Where in your code is `user_key`? Your posted code and error *do not match*.

Comment: I edited Martjin, thanks. So now where am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

if `username` was in `userlist`, then that means that the variable `key` would never have been created. Outside of the conditional structure, perhaps do something like `key = ''`

Comment: But first I created a user with creating a key, after that I want to update.

Comment: @AmyObrian You only created `key` in the conditional structure. Do `key = ''` outside of it

Comment: it didnt work, I couldnt understand. I mean firstly I created my key why cant I use it while I am updating ? Can you write me all the true codes ?

Comment: @AmyObrian You haven't created your `key`. It's not in your code. It could only be created IF username is in `userlist`

Comment: It could only be created IF username is in userlist = wrong  if username not in userlist = true  ??

Comment: So I havent got any user in my datastore, look at codes, if not in userlist create a user with key. isnt it right ?

Comment: @AmyObrian I think you're a little confused here. You only have `key = ` in your conditional structure. if username is not in userlist, then you will create `key`. But if you don't, then key will never have been created. That's why you're trying to reference the variable `key` but it never has been created. Obviously, username is in the userlist

Comment: Yes I agree with you but I want to say that, my userlist is empty. I added a user first so now I have one user in my userlist. Did I use key? Yes I used because my user wasnt in my userlist. If I add that user again, it doesnt add, why? because I have already that user. And I couldnt update, because "key error".

Answer (score 0):

```
def post(self):
        username = self.request.get("contentb")
        header, response = client.request('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name='+username+'&count=5000')
        ids = [str(id) for id in json.loads(response)["ids"]]
        messages = []
        userlist = [user.username for user in User.query().fetch(projection=["username"])]
        if username not in userlist:
            user = User()
            user.username = username
            user.follower_list = ids
            key = user.put()
            messages.append("Ok we added you")

        #now user should be in; lets fetch it (update to your needs)
        user = [user for user in User.query().fetch(projection=["username"]) if user.username == username][0]      
        followerlist = [user.follower_list[0] for user in User.query().filter(User.username == username).fetch(projection=["follower_list"])]
        if len(set(followerlist)-set(ids)) == 0:
            messages.append("No one has unfollowed you :)")
        else:
            for i in set(followerlist)-set(ids):
                messages.append(str(i) + " " + "unfollowed you")  

        user.follower_list = ids
        user.put()
        messages.append("We updated your followerlist")
```

Comment: I get this error :  'You cannot set property values of a projection entity')
ReadonlyPropertyError: You cannot set property values of a projection entity

Comment: does user.get() after its fetch help?